# "ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list" is thrown when using a for x in list

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm trying to remove bullets from a list when they collide with a wall. The program removes some bullets correctly, but eventually throws a "ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list" error when a bullet hits a wall.

The error occurs in the delete() method of the Bullet class and only occurs with bullets fired from the enemies. Bullets fired from the player do not produce any errors.

```
class Bullet(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, player, list):
        super().__init__()
        self.speed(0)
        self.ht()
        self.pu()
        self.color("white")
        self.goto(player.xcor(), player.ycor())
        self.setheading(player.heading())
        self.forward(40)
        self.list = list
        self.st()
    
    # move the bullet
    def move(self):
        self.forward(15)
        if self.ycor()>300 or self.ycor()< -300:
            self.delete()
            
    # delete the bullet
    def delete(self):
        self.ht()
        self.list.remove(self)




def update(counter):
    if len(enemies)>0 and player.alive: 
        # move each of the enemies
        for alien in enemies:
            alien.move()
            if alien.ycor() < - 200 or alien.distance(player)<30:
                player.delete()

        # randomly select an enemy to fire a bullet.
        if counter % 10 == 0:
            index = random.randint(0,len(enemies)-1)
            bullets.append(Bullet(enemies[index],bullets))

        # move each bullet fired by the enemies
        for bullet in bullets[:]:
            bullet.move()
            # check for collision with player
            if bullet.distance(player)<20:
                player.delete()
            # check for collision with a wall
            for wall in walls[:]:
                if bullet.distance(wall)<15:
                    wall.strike()
                    bullet.delete()
                        
                
        # move bullets fired by the player
        for bullet in player.rounds:
            bullet.move()
            # check for collision with an enemy
            for alien in enemies:
                if bullet.distance(alien)<20:
                    bullet.delete()
                    alien.delete(enemies)
    
        counter += 1
        screen.ontimer(lambda:update(counter),30)
```

I'm having trouble with this problem because the program uses a for loop to iterate over a list of bullets using the syntax for bullet in bullets. Although the bullet presumably exists in the list, the program can't remove it when it tries to do so from the same list.

I attempted to resolve the issue by making a copy of the list, but that didn't help me fix the error.

Comment: When you want to remove items from a list while iterating over that list, a common solution is to iterate over a copy of the list, *but* you need to remove items from the original list, not from the copy. Also, why does the Bullet class contain a list?

Comment: Apart from what @jarmod said `list` isba terrible name for anything and it's gonna generate hard to find bugs sooner than later imho. Don't have the full context, but bullet class should not have a list of bullets as an attribute.

Comment: Please could you use a [minimal, reproducible amount](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), instead of pasting in all your code? It would make it much easier to debug.

Comment: Thank y'all for your suggestions:

Comment: Using "list" as a name can be confusing. In this context, "the list" refers to the collection of bullets. The program will maintain two lists of bullets: one for bullets fired by enemies and the other for bullets fired by the player. It may seem circular for a bullet object to store the list it belongs to, but I cannot think of a better way for the bullet to identify which list it should remove itself from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably occurring because you are attempting to delete the same bullet multiple times because it is satisfying multiple wall collision conditions. If it's not important to call `wall.strike()` for each colliding wall, then we can just add a `break` to exit the for loop. Otherwise, we can do a conditional delete.

```
        for wall in walls[:]:
            if bullet.distance(wall)<15:
                wall.strike()
                if bullet not in bullet.list:
                    bullet.delete()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I ended up using a try/except, but I tried your solution and it worked beautifully. It helped me better understand my program.